# JSE Github Organisation

Tags: discussion

So I've noticed having read back at a lot of answers, both my own and other, that we sometimes provide code that could be turned into a full plugin.

An example being the answer I wrote a few minutes ago [here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/15937/168).

I was wondering if people would be interested in a Joomla StackExchange Github Organisation, by which we could have public repositories for any installable plugins/modules we've written.

It means that they're stored in 1 generic location, anyone can contribute, and we can reference them in future answers if need be.

If a couple of you are interested, I'll set it up and give you permissions.

Comment: Great idea man... I would love to see that implemented, for the sake of JSE's own good. I'm not a developer myself, and I have a hard time using Github, but I understand basics of how it operates and why it is indispensable in process of shared development.

Comment: this is awesome :) count me in

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right, I've created an organisation on Github, and added the first repository there:

https://github.com/Joomla-StackExchange

If any of you would like access, let me know your Github username and I'll add you to the list.

If you don't have much experience with Github, feel free to go on the [Joomla Chat Group](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14071/joomla) and I'll be more than happy to point you in the right direction.

---

#### Members on the JSE Github team so far:

**Admin:**

- Lodder
- Valentin Despa
- JohanPW

**Member:**

- Rene Korss
- Joomler
- Ruchika

I've given **members** write permissions so you can now push code where and when you like.

Comment: please add me *rishiv3*

Comment: Great, please add me as well: vdespa

Comment: Great idea! Awesome job @Lodder! Add me too - renekorss. I have two custom form fields in gists right now, which I developed lately. How should we go about this? We should think about logical structuring. I don't think that generating new repo for every little peace of code is very smart. We should somehow group them. I was thinking about structure relative to Joomla! structure, but that would mean we will end up with only one repo and that would turn messy too.

Comment: @Rene, I was thinking about having a beta repo which contains all the unfinished code snippets. When they are stable extensions, they can then be pushed into their own repo. Just an idea though. Maybe someone else has a better approach

Comment: @Lodder Okay. Fine by me. Except for example, custom form field can't be standalone extension. How to deal with this kind of code? Please add us to Github org then :)

Comment: Added you all to the github organisation

Comment: @ReneKorss - If it can't be added as a standalone extension, then I think maybe a repo called "Docs" or "Extras" or "Scripts" could be created to put all code snippet like that in

Comment: @Lodder I was thinking that I'll create `formFields` repo where every custom field is in its own directory. Then we can have readme file for every field and main readme file for basic custom form fields info. What you think about this?

Comment: @Lodder the idea is really great. kindly add me : ruchikanagarkar

Comment: @ReneKorss - sounds good ;)

Comment: @Ruchika - added you too ;)

Comment: Guess I'm late to the party, but this is a great idea, please add me too: *dospuntos*

Comment: @Lodder I'll take an invite too: dfritsch

Comment: Also, we might want to make sure that we license the code in the same way that JSE would be: MIT license per http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange

Comment: @DavidFritsch - invited. I know that if you post actual code as an answer then it must be under the MIT, however let's say you fork an extension, like I did (registeredOnly). The original license was GPL, so when forking, must I use the same license? Also, If I then add a **link** to that repo in an answer, then does the MIT situation conflict with the GPL? Cause as far as I know, the MIT license only applies for code that is actually added to an answer, not code that belongs on a 3rd party site

Comment: I believe it would only apply to unlicenced code, so I mostly mean if we add code there that is unlicenced. :)

Comment: Hi mate @Lodder - add me as well...

Comment: @Ffrewin sent you an invite :)

Answer (score 2):

Adding my first plugin [here](https://github.com/Joomla-StackExchange/editorTemplate) for this [question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/18441/different-templates-for-viewing-and-editing-articles)

I also put [update.xml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Joomla-StackExchange/editorTemplate/master/update.xml) file for `<updateservers>` in the root of that repo, but it seems doesn't work. I have clicked the Find Updates button at the *Extensions > Manage > Update* page many times and also clicked the *Clear Cache* button, but it still said *"There are no updates available at the moment. Please check again later."*

Any idea?

Comment: In the `update.xml` (for plugins), you need to add (in your case) `<folder>system</folder>`

Comment: I believe you'll also need to remove `plg_` from `<element>plg_editortemplate</element>`

Comment: @Lodder Done, but still doesn't work

Comment: I've just tried parsing the XML file and it works, so Github allow this, but did you uninstall, then reinstall the extension to test the udpate?

Comment: Oopps, it's working now after several clicks and clearing cache. Thanks @Lodder

Comment: no worries... ;)

Comment: @Lodder just uploaded it to [JED](http://imgur.com/a/CIVqS) too lol, hopefully they will approve it and it could bring more attention to JSE.

Comment: You'll be waiting about 6 months for that to be approved :P

Comment: @Lodder Really? lol