# What is the policy on Joomla SE for uploading installables?

Tags: discussion

I recently posted a question and got no interest or answers, and since then have created a simple class and installable component for the problem.  It's nothing fancy, just a useful utility that would be handy for anyone interested in the subject.  I have no desire to publish/support it so wanted to know if I can upload it to the question or as an answer without violating any policy.

**Update**

I've humbly uploaded a component that extends the core logging abilities of Joomla at [JSE Github](https://github.com/Joomla-StackExchange/glogger). It was done quickly, with no planning or design, but has turned out to be quite a handy tool to have for my logging challenges.  Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Never mind, I just realized we can't upload any files at all, lol

Comment: You can send me your GitHub username and I can add you.

Comment: @ValentinDespa, I went ahead and created a repository with my own account (gdpodesta), before I realized you had to do something for the Joomla Repository aspect.  I'll redo if you can "add" me and give me instructions to put it there instead.

Comment: Invitation is sent. Fell free to create another repository here. https://github.com/Joomla-StackExchange

Comment: @ValentinDespa Thank you good sir.  Going to spend a day or two working out real-world kinks, then post the new and improved v1 there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, read your question and believe me, I'm very interested to post an answer but unfortunately I found myself not capable enough of giving any solution lol.

Anyway, on this [topic](https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279/jse-github-organisation) @Lodder encouraged us to upload any installable extensions to [JSE Github Organisation](https://github.com/Joomla-StackExchange)
Maybe you can upload it there?

Comment: That's perfect...didn't even know it existed.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're interested in the solution I created or not, but I've posted it at JSE for now.  It was quite ad-hoc, so the code is *anything* but elegant, but I may build it properly with enough interest, and any feedback that I may get.

Answer (score 2):

Well, not sure if I did it right or not, but my initial solution is at https://github.com/Joomla-StackExchange/glogger.  Please be kind, I used a component generator, and tweaked it a bit for my needs.  The Logging Class is an extension of the Jlog class, and scope creep became an issue.  I'm going to use it in my real world application for awhile, and then, if there's interest, I'll be refining and repairing it as interest and need dictate.

Answer (score 1):

Saw you question too, but wasn't my area either. Although I *was* eager to get some more flowers

If you do add it to the Github page provided in @webchuns's answer, I'd also suggest answering your post with a link to the repo. Doesn't violate any policy as far as I'm concerned, as you're sharing your solution ;)

Comment: Last time I sent flowers, the guards at Buckingham Palace said that nobody by the name of Lodder lived there, so wouldn't take the delivery :(

Comment: Lodder could you add me to the repo too? Here is my [github account](https://github.com/webchun). Thanks!

Comment: @webchun - invitation sent ;)

Comment: @Lodder Thanks!